# How to get books credentials by just inputing ISBN number in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, network-programming, google-books

So I basically new to python programming. My teacher ask me to make a program that get you books information from google books. So basicly you just run a python file with ISBN number as an input. And then after you input the number, the output my teacher wanted is: Book title, Author, Publisher, and release date of the books.

[image: This is the picture of output I need to get. Judul is title, pengarang is author, penerbit is a publisher, and tanggal is the date]

My teacher give me a tips that i can use json library that already prepared by python3. I already have the googleapis key, but I kinda lost of what to do next in the process. Can please someone help me to solve this? thank you

Comment: Please post your code to show your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Please check requests library in order to get required data from the web.

The following link would be helpful;

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/